# IndexError string index out of range when referencing first character

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

Here is my code (currently):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
conn.text_factory = str  #bugger 8-bit bytestrings
cur = conn.cursor()

reader = csv.reader(open(csvfile, "rU"), delimiter = '\t')
for Number, Name, Message, Datetime, Type in reader:

# populate subscriber table
if str(Number)[0] == '1': # errors on this line
  tmpNumber = str(Number)[1:]
  Number = int(tmpNumber)
cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO subscriber (name, phone_number) VALUES (?,?)', (Name, Number))

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

It returns this error on the line commented to indicate where the error lies:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

All of the numbers have values, but if the phone number starts with a 1 I want to remove the 1 before inserting it into the database. Why won't this work? I've converted it to a string before trying to reference the first character, so I don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are getting an empty string.  Try replacing your if statement with the following and see if it works.

```
if str(Number).startswith('1'):
```

(Edited to reflect @kindall 's suggestion of using `startswith` instead of slicing `[:1]`).

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now on to figure out why no data is being written to the database....

Comment: It isn't letting me mark this as the answer, I guess I have to wait 7 minutes first. Any ideas why nothing is being read from the file into the database? Standard csv file, tab-delimited....

Comment: is nothing being read in by `csv` or is nothing being added to the database? is it possible that you just have lines that are empty?  I would add an `else` clause that prints out everything read when you get an empty string.  All you need is one empty Number column to produce the error.  Also, you should not need to convert Number to a string, it should be a string already, so you'd need to convert it to an int first...

Comment: are you committing the transaction? call `conn.commit()` after your insert statement

Comment: `str(Number).startswith('1')` would be more idiomatic than slicing IMHO.

Comment: @kindall : that does read better. but, how do you know that it's more idiomatic? Is there a guide somewhere? (I particularly see this come up with the ternary `A if <bool> else B`)

Comment: The thing I like about it is that it is clearer ("reads better") and if you need to change how many characters you're interested in you don't have to change it in two places ("don't repeat yourself").